# Using requests.Session() in Python as a context manager for a variable number of consecutive requests

Tags: python, session, python-requests, contextmanager

I would like to use an object as a context manager, but control the moment when the `__exit__` method is called.

In particular, I am using the `Session()` object offered by the Python requests module, which can be used as a context-manager. I understand that by simply using e.g. `requests.get()` a new `Session()` object is created and destroyed each time, while instead persisting a session should give a shorter response time and keep headers, etc for all requests within the session. I would like to make `x` requests with a `Session()`, then close the session and make `y` requests with a new `Session()` object, and so on until my code has finished running. However, since I have various calls to `Session().get()` in my code, I do not want to have it all contained within a `with` block. What are my options?

This is probably a simple problem for more experienced Python programmers, but I find myself stuck in figuring out how to organise my code. Any ideas about how this could be implemented? Happy to give any clarifications if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Note that calling `Session()` always creates a new Python object, here a `requests` session. This means that if you have, as you say

> various calls to Session().get() in my code

then you are necessarily creating a new Session object each and every time. There is no way to wrap your code as written with something magic to reuse the same session. You have two main solutions.

#### 1. Create one session object and reuse it.

Since your code probably looks something like this (where three independent sessions are created):

```
Session().get(...)
# ...
Session().get(...)
# ...
Session().get(...)
```

Instead, create one session reuse it each time. You would need to modify your code as such:

```
mysession = Session() # create a new session

mysession.get(...)
# ...
mysession.get(...) # session is reused
# ...
mysession.get(...) # session is reused

# finished with session, make sure to close it!
mysession.close()
```

This avoids putting everything in a `with` block.

#### 2. Place your code in a `with` block.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(...)
    s.get(...)
    s.get(...)
# session s automatically closed here
```

As noted in the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=session#session-objects), the `with` context manager

> will make sure the session is closed as soon as the with block is exited, even if unhandled exceptions occurred.

That is the main benefit - you don't have to remember to close the session, which is very easy to forget particularly when you are making a large number of requests.

You note that you do not want to have all your session calls contained within a `with` block. One recommendation is to handle all of your requests in a `with` block, then process the resulting responses outside the block. This would a) separate your code into "get remote data" and "process remote data" sections, making it a little easier to read, however, without looking at your code/logic, this might not be possible.